# Is there a way to download ALL app updates at once in Amazon App Store?

Tags: amazon-appstore

Device: Verizon Droid X
Androrid: stock Froyo 2.2 ROM
Amazon Market app: latest version (updated 3/3/2013)

When I open the list of apps to be update in Google Play Store, there is a button on top right which lets me download and install ALL updates at once, instead of doing it app by app.

Is there such a capability in the app for Amazon App Store?

Comment: As a note: this is Verizon Droid X, with stock Froyo 2.2 ROM and latest version (updated 3/3/2013) of Amazon Market app.

Answer (score 0):

On the Kindle Fire, on the list of apps to be updated, there is an Update All button at the top right. You can update one-by-one or all-at-once, but there's no facility to update a selected group.

Comment: No such button here (Latest version of App Store app on Verizon Droid X, stock Froyo 2.2)